# XCode Warning "Expression Result Unused" for mathematical statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting a warning while doing this

```
CGFloat viewHeight = ([self.quotaArray count]*kROW_HEIGHT) + kHEADER_HEIGHT + kFOOTER_HEIGHT;
```

Basically this math statement returns me the height of my table view, which is the

```
(number of rows * row height) + header height + footer height
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add the definition of kROW_HEIGHT, kHEADER_HEIGHT, kFOOTER_HEIGHT? Are they only numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: You have something like:

```
#define kHEADER_HEIGHT 3;
```

So, the line of code you give turns into:

```
CGFloat viewHeight = ([self.quotaArray count]*1) + 3; + 2;
```

Which is valid; the last part produces a warning. (`+2` is a valid expression, which does nothing but produce the value 2, hence the warning.)

So, remove the semicolon from your define, or, even better, stop using `#define` when a static const int would do. (Because you can't get crazy errors like this if you're just using an int.)

Comment: brilliant! that did it. how should I declare static const int? I shall use that in future.

Comment: So, instead of `#define kHEADER_HEIGHT 3` I would say `static const int XYZHeaderHeight = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the variable after it? That warning is telling you that you created a CGFloat called viewHeight and not using it in your code

Comment: Yes I am. The warning only highlights the last part of the statement so I dont think it's what you are referring to. The warning you are referring to would be `Unused variable viewHeight`.